# How to personalize the command prompt?

Tags: bash, ps1

I just recently (re)installed Ubuntu on my pc and I have a slight "problem". I can't figure out what commands (?) I should write in my bash_profile, to have the following result:

```
< User>@< full current path>/>>
```

Right now, I merely have the `>>` at the end. I know about the `/w` variable but I just can't stand the tilde it begins with. Is there anyway to get what I get with `/w` but without the tilde? Thank you very much in advance.

EDIT: Here's the whole `bash_profile`:

```
export PS1="\w/>>"
```

Comment: Can you add in your whole bash _profile into your question just by [editing](http://askubuntu.com/posts/709170/edit) it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**EDIT: This works, but murus solution is the better one, as he is totally right about .bash_profile and .bashrc and also uses built-ins instead of external programs!**

I also don't find an option, but you could use

```
`pwd`
```

which executes `pwd` and writes the result (the path) in the promt.

The full path as you wanted it above would be:

```
PS1="\u@`pwd`/>>"
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thank you very much :D

Answer (score 5):

First, don't use `.bash_profile`, since Ubuntu comes with a `.profile` with useful settings which would be ignored if you use `.bash_profile`. Use `.bashrc`.

Second, the current working directory is stored in the `PWD` variable. You do not need to use command substitution for it:

```
muru:~ $ PS1='$PWD $ '
/home/muru $
```

So, just add the following line to `.bashrc`:

```
PS1='\u@$PWD/>>'
```